# View2D Zoom 2D View hotkeys

Tags: uv, image, shortcut

I'd like to use Alt + Right mouse to zoom in the UV/Image Editor. Currently, it's set to Ctrl + Right Mouse

View2D has a hotkey for Zoom 2D View set to Ctrl + Right Mouse. I changed it to Alt + Right Mouse, then Save User Settings, and in the UV/Image Editor, zoom is still using Ctrl + Right Mouse.

userpref.blend is also writable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zoom setting you find listed under View2D refer to flat layouts such as dopesheet, graph editor, VSE...

To adjust the UV/Image Editor zoom settings you need to alter the zoom settings found under Image.

[image]